# Disable quick find (links only) on firefox inside a textarea / text input

Tags: firefox, input, textarea, user-input

I have some issue when entering text in my website with Firefox.
If I type an apostrophe >'<, Firefox start its "Quick Find (Links Only)" feature. Normally it is disabled inside textarea or input text. But not in my case. Any idea on how to disable this feature when typing inside textarea or text input ?

Here is the HTML of my inputs :

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="id_title" required class="form-control" maxlength="75" />

<textarea name="summary" rows="2" maxlength="220" id="id_summary" required class="form-control" cols="80">
</textarea>
```